# How do I get the root element name of an XML document using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

Using Nokogiri, I would like to determine the name of the root element.

I thought that doing an XPath query for `/` would do the trick but apparently that node name is "document"?

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML('<foo>Hello</foo>')
doc.xpath('/').first.name    # => "document" 
doc.xpath('/foo').first.name # => "foo"
```

How can I get the string "foo" for the root node name without knowing it ahead of time?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`/*` should work:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML('<foo>Hello</foo>')

doc.xpath('/*').first.name
#=> "foo"
```

or using [`Nokogiri::XML::Document#root`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-i-root):

```
doc.root.name
#=> "foo"
```