# Is there a way to find the name of root tag of a Nokogiri::XML::Element?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

Is there a way to get the name of root tag's name of a `Nokogiri::XML::Element`? After referring to [How do I get the root element name of an XML document using Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248091/how-do-i-get-the-root-element-name-of-an-xml-document-using-nokogiri) I tried using `Nokogiri::XML::Element.xpath('/*').first.name` which seems to work only for `Nokogiri::XML::Document`. Is there a direct way to extract the name of the root tag of a `Nokogiri::XML::Element` other than converting it into a `Nokogiri::XML::Document` and use the above way?

Example:

```
child_element =
  <<~XML
      <child2>
        <developer>
          <name>xyz</name>
          <email>xyz@abc</email>
          <url>url</url>
          <roles>
            <role>owner</role>
            <role>developer</role>
          </roles>
        </developer>
        <name>Child2</name>
        <qualification>Qualification2</qualification>
      </child2>
  XML

child_nokogiri_document = Nokogiri::XML(child_element, &:noblanks)

puts child_nokogiri_document.xpath('//developer').xpath('/*').first.name #=> child2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A `Nokogiri::XML::Element` responds to `name`. Maybe you could provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out!

`puts child_nokogiri_document.xpath('//developer').first.name #=> developer`

I tried many ways but kind of missed out this quick fix.